# PyAudio with callback - corrupted audio output

Tags: python, real-time, portaudio, pyaudio

A coworker and me are using pyaudio with callback function. Very rarely we get an error in audio output signal.
We have seen two kind of errors:

- A block of 16 samples has the samples from pre-previous block.
- A part of the signal is zero. Its length in samples is the multiple of 16.

The (simplified) version of the callback function is here:

```
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
  if self.dataIndex+frame_count < self.length or self.length == "infinite":
    whatToDo = pyaudio.paContinue
  else:
    whatToDo = pyaudio.paComplete

  # RME needs 24 bit value disguised as 32 bit. The lower 8 bits have to be zero.
  dataStr = ((self.playData[:,self.dataIndex:self.dataIndex+frame_count].T*
              (2**23-1)).astype('<i4') << 8).astype('<i4').tostring()

  self.dataIndex += frame_count
  return (dataStr, whatToDo)
```

Because the problem occurs very rarely it is hard to try different things.

I am suspicious about using a Python function for a callback with real-time demands. What about if garbage collection is done in the critical time? We have seen the error even when there is nothing but time.sleep() in the main thread, so I guess this excludes a problem with GIL.

Further info:

- soundcard: RME Hammerfall DSP Multiface II
- using ASIO driver, 10 channels input and 10 channels output, we've tried different samples/frame settings
- PyAudio version 0.2.7
- Python 2.7.5
- OS: Windows 7

Comment: you should try (I understand that it might be hard) to create a minimal complete code example that reliably reproduces the issue (it is best if it doesn't require specialized hardware, drivers).

Comment: The bug is not deterministic and occurs rarely. Based on current experience I don't think we could break it down much further in a reasonable time. So far it even seems that which of the both errors we see depends on which computer the program runs (although both computers, hw and sw, are practically identical). Solving it isn't critical but I would at least like to understand some possible causes.